# Perform a search on main collection field and array of objects simultaneously

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have my document structure as below:

```
{
     "codeId" : 8.7628945723895E13, // long numeric value stored in scientific notation by Mongodb
    "problemName" : "Hardware Problem", 
    "problemErrorCode" : "97695686856", 
    "status" : "active", 
    "problemDescription" : "ghdsojgnhsdjgh sdojghsdjoghdghd i0dhgjodshgddsgsdsdfghsdfg", 
    "subProblems" : [
        {
            "codeId" : 8.76289457238896E14, 
            "problemName" : "Some problem", 
            "problemErrorCode" : "57790389503490249640", 
            "problemDescription" : "This is edited", 
            "status" : "active", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("589476eeae39b20b1c15535b")
        }, 
        ...
     ]
}
```

I have a search field which should search by `codeId` which basically serves as `parentCodeID` in search fields as shown below

[image]

Now, along with `parentIdCode` I want to search for `codeId`, `problemCode`, `problemName` and `problemDescription` as well.

How do I query the submodules with a regex search and at same time tag some parent field with `"$or"` clause etc. to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
 query = {
        '$or': [{
            "codeId":somevalue
        }, {
            "subProblems.codeId": {
                "$regex": searchValue,
                "$options": "i"
            }
        }, {
           //rest of sub modules fields
        }]
    };
```